# ItemsControl inside existing Canvas

Tags: c#, xaml, itemscontrol, windows-8

I am trying to accomplish the following.

1) Have a canvas control on my page, with a background image that is scalable and pannable.  This works OK with what I have.
2) Display a set of controls within the canvas.  This is envisaged to be similar to the way the Bing homepage displays hotspots on the image shown there.  The controls need to move around on the canvas as the image is panned/zoomed.

I've tried the following

```
    <Canvas Name="PanoCanvas" >
        <Canvas.Background>
            <ImageBrush x:Name="PanoImage" ImageSource="/Images/OtherImages/PanoBackound.jpg" Stretch="None" />
        </Canvas.Background>
        <ItemsControl Name="POIPresenter">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <uc:PointOfInterest />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding TopPosition}" />
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding LeftPosition}" />
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Canvas>
```

and set the ItemsSource of POIPresenter in code behind, but the user controls are displaying on top of one another on the left (at 0,0).

I have tried moving the canvas declarations inside the ItemsPanelTemplate, but then my declarations to set the scale/centre of the image do not work - they can't find the PanoCanvas control.

Can anyone point out the painfully obvious thing that I'm doing wring here, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you can simplify as follows:

```
<ItemsControl ...>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas>
                <Canvas.Background>...</Canvas.Background>
            </Canvas>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

That is, use one `Canvas` instead of two.

Other than that, look for binding errors in the output window. Perhaps the `TopPosition` and `LeftPosition` properties aren't being correctly resolved.

Comment: That was what I tried (simplifying the canvas inside the ItemsPanelTemplate) but then I couldn't reference it from my code behind.  I'll give it another go - maybe I did it wrong...

Comment: OK, forget that - you won't be able to reference it easily because it's generated by the `ItemsPanelTemplate`. You'd have to use something like `VisualTreeHelper` to get at it. What about your main problem? Is it a binding issue?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the output window, and the other properties are binding as expected in the control itself.

Comment: I have just added another textblock to output the TopPosition and LeftPosition inside the item template, and they are binding ok there, although admittedly they are being cast to strings for display.  They are Doubles in the model.

Comment: Try changing the `ItemsControl` to a `ListBox` and the `ContentPresenter` style to a `ListBoxItem` style, just for a test. If that works, I think you need to use an ItemsControl that hosts its items inside `ContentControl` instances instead of `ContentPresenter`s

Comment: Thanks Kent, it didn't make any difference, unfortunately.  In the end I fudged it as this is only for a proof of concept app and this functionality was a "nice-to-have".  It's still up in the air as to how to do it, though, if anyone has more suggestions. :)